# cleaning up the data from a webscraper

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I've been building a webscraper, and ultimately I'd like to get it to key value pairs because of the way the data is set up, here's an example the first output from this webscraper and what I have done so far to clean the data:

```
# each pass of the webscraper appends the wrapper table to a table
# the first entry looks like this:
new_set5001[0]=
"About 403 W Main Street, Cleveland, MO 64734\nDirections:From Kansas City-South to Cleveland Mo., D-Highway & Y-Highway turn west onto Main St., go through the the 4 way stop. home is on the south side (left). From Kansas us 69 Highway & 247th St. exit, east to Cleveland to the house on the south side.\nGeneral Description\nMLS Number\n2225041\nCounty\nCass\nCity\nCleveland\nSub Div\nCleveland\nType\nSingle Family\nFloor Plan Description\nRanch\nBdrms\n3\nBaths Full\n1\nBaths Half\n1\nAge Description\n101 Years/More\nYear Built\n1900\nSqft Main\n1307\nSQFT MAIN SOURCE\nPublic Record\nBelow Grade Finished Sq Ft\n0\nBelow Grade Finished Sq Ft Source\nPublic Record\nSqft\n1307\nLot Size\n100' X 172'\nSchool District\nCass-Midway\nS Terms\nCash\nInterior Features\nFireplace?\nY\nFireplace Description\nLiving Room\nBasement\nN\nBasement Description\nCrawl Space\nDining Area Description\nEat-In Kitchen\nUtility Room\nOff The Kitchen\nInterior Features\nFixer Up, Partial Carpeting\nExterior / Construction\nGarage/Parking?\nN\nConstruction\nBrick Trim, Frame\nArchitecture\nOther\nRoof\nComposition\nLot Description\nCity Lot\nIn Floodplain\nNo\nInside City Limits\nYes\nStreet Maintenance\nPaved\nExterior Features\nFixer Up\nUtility Information\nCentral Air\nN\nHeat\nNatural Gas\nCool\nNone\nWater\nCity/Public\nSewer\nCity/Public\nFinancial Information\nS Terms\nCash\nHoa Amount\n$0\nTax\n$1,005\nSpecial Tax\n$0\nTotal Tax\n$1,005\nType Of Ownership\nPrivate\nWill Sell\nCash, Conventional"

# next I split the lines 

new_set5001a = []
for i in range(len(new_set5001)):
    new_set5001a.append(new_set5001[i].splitlines())
#this yields a nested list
# passed these to a list of arrays for operations

np_arrrays = []
for array in new_set5001a:
    np_arrays.append(np.array(array))
```

now working one 1 array at a time I get exactly what I need from the following function

```
def clean_data(arr, feature_list):

    new = []
    
    for val in feature_list:
        try:
            y = (np.argwhere(arr==val)+1).flatten()
            z = np.where(arr==val, arr[y], None)
            z1 = z[z!=None][0]
            new.append(z1)
        except:
            new.append(None)
    return dict(zip(feature_list, new))

feature_list = ['MLS Number','County', 'City', 'Sub Div', 'Type',
        'Floor Plan Description', 'Bdrms',
       'Baths Full', 'Baths Half','Year Built', 'Sqft Main', 
       'SQFT MAIN SOURCE', 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft',
       'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft Source', 'Lot Size', 'School District',
       'Fireplace?', 'Fireplace Description',
       'Basement', 'Basement Description',
       'Garage/Parking?', 'Construction', 
       'Architecture', 'Roof',  'Lot Description',
      'In Floodplain', 'Inside City Limits', 
       'Street Maintenance','Central Air', 'Heat', 
       'Cool', 'Water','Sewer']

clean_data(np_arrays[0], feature_list)
{'MLS Number': '2212446',
 'County': 'Cass',
 'City': 'Garden City',
 'Sub Div': 'Hedge Trails',
 'Type': 'Single Family',
 'Floor Plan Description': 'Ranch',
 'Bdrms': '2',
 'Baths Full': '1',
 'Baths Half': '0',
 'Year Built': '1974',
 'Sqft Main': '960',
 'SQFT MAIN SOURCE': 'Public Record',
 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft': '0',
 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft Source': 'Public Record',
 'Lot Size': '78x120',
 'School District': 'Sherwood',
 'Fireplace?': 'N',
 'Fireplace Description': None,
 'Basement': 'N',
 'Basement Description': 'Crawl Space',
 'Garage/Parking?': 'Y',
 'Construction': 'Frame, Vinyl Siding',
 'Architecture': 'Traditional',
 'Roof': 'Composition',
 'Lot Description': 'City Lot, Corner Lot',
 'In Floodplain': 'No',
 'Inside City Limits': None,
 'Street Maintenance': None,
 'Central Air': 'Y',
 'Heat': 'Forced Air Gas, Natural Gas',
 'Cool': 'Central Electric',
 'Water': 'City/Public',
 'Sewer': 'City/Public'}
```

My approach now is to loop through again and get a list of key, value pairs, but I am not quite there yet

```
new2 = []
for i in range(len(new_set5001a)):
    x = np_arrays[i]
    for val in feature_list:
        try:
            y = (np.argwhere(x==val)+1).flatten()
            z = np.where(x==val, x[y], None)
            z1 = z[z!=None][0]
            new2.append({val:z1})
        except:
            new2.append({val:None})
```

so the output of new2 is the following:

```
[{'MLS Number': '2225041'},
 {'County': 'Cass'},
 {'City': 'Cleveland'},
 {'Sub Div': 'Cleveland'},
 {'Type': 'Single Family'},
 {'Floor Plan Description': 'Ranch'},
 {'Bdrms': '3'},
 {'Baths Full': '1'},
 {'Baths Half': '1'},
 {'Year Built': '1900'},
 {'Sqft Main': '1307'},
 {'SQFT MAIN SOURCE': 'Public Record'},
 {'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft': '0'},
 {'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft Source': 'Public Record'},
 {'Lot Size': "100' X 172'"},
 {'School District': 'Cass-Midway'},
 {'Fireplace?': 'Y'},
 {'Fireplace Description': 'Living Room'},
 {'Basement': 'N'},
 {'Basement Description': 'Crawl Space'},
 {'Garage/Parking?': 'N'},
 {'Construction': 'Brick Trim, Frame'},
 {'Architecture': 'Other'},
 {'Roof': 'Composition'},
 {'Lot Description': 'City Lot'},
 {'In Floodplain': 'No'},
 {'Inside City Limits': 'Yes'},
 {'Street Maintenance': 'Paved'},
 {'Central Air': 'N'},
 {'Heat': 'Natural Gas'},
 {'Cool': 'None'},
 {'Water': 'City/Public'},
 {'Sewer': 'City/Public'},
 {'MLS Number': '2212446'},
 {'County': 'Cass'},
 {'City': 'Garden City'},
 {'Sub Div': 'Hedge Trails'},
 {'Type': 'Single Family'},
 {'Floor Plan Description': 'Ranch'},
 {'Bdrms': '2'},
 {'Baths Full': '1'},
 {'Baths Half': '0'},
 {'Year Built': '1974'},
 {'Sqft Main': '960'},
 {'SQFT MAIN SOURCE': 'Public Record'},
 {'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft': '0'},
 {'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft Source': 'Public Record'},
 {'Lot Size': '78x120'},
 {'School District': 'Sherwood'},
 {'Fireplace?': 'N'},
 {'Fireplace Description': None},
 {'Basement': 'N'},
 {'Basement Description': 'Crawl Space'},
 {'Garage/Parking?': 'Y'},
 {'Construction': 'Frame, Vinyl Siding'},
 {'Architecture': 'Traditional'},
 {'Roof': 'Composition'},
 {'Lot Description': 'City Lot, Corner Lot'},
 {'In Floodplain': 'No'},
 {'Inside City Limits': None},
 {'Street Maintenance': None},
 {'Central Air': 'Y'},
 {'Heat': 'Forced Air Gas, Natural Gas'},
 {'Cool': 'Central Electric'},
 {'Water': 'City/Public'},
 {'Sewer': 'City/Public'}]
```

So I can see that this is not quite correct but I don't know how to proceed from here

Comment: why do you use`r'xx'` for the replace string but not for the regex string

Comment: Judging by what you wrote, you need `\\n(.*?)\\n` and replace with `:$1,\n` in VSCode.

Comment: Replace with `': '$1',\n'` and use @Wiktor's find regex.  See https://regex101.com/r/76SZEl/1  and just remove the `'general description': ` at the beginning by hand.  The last entry might have to be fixed by hand as well.

Comment: Plus as you see from the regex101 demo your data is much more complicated that it at first appears - I think it'll be a lot of work to get it right in one regex.

Comment: I was going to post an answer for you until I discovered line 3 of your first sample has an uneven number. So, splash 1. `Rooms\nLiving Room\nLevel 1\nKitchen\nLevel 1\nLiving Rm- 2nd\nLevel B\nBathroom Full\nLevel 1\nMaster Bedroom\nLevel 1\nMaster Bathroom\nLevel 1\nSecond Bedroom\nLevel 1\nThird Bedroom\nLevel 1\nFourth Bedroom\nLevel B\n2nd Full Bath\nLevel B`

Answer (score 1):

Three seperate regex need to be performed.
But, it's a moot point now as I said in my comments:

*line 3 of your first sample has an uneven number.*
`Rooms\nLiving Room\nLevel 1\nKitchen\nLevel 1\nLiving Rm- 2nd\nLevel B\nBathroom Full\nLevel 1\nMaster Bedroom\nLevel 1\nMaster Bathroom\nLevel 1\nSecond Bedroom\nLevel 1\nThird Bedroom\nLevel 1\nFourth Bedroom\nLevel B\n2nd Full Bath\nLevel B`

So, basically the 3rd regex is offset by 1, which makes a world of difference.

Regex 1:  `(?:\[{|}\]|[^\S\r\n]*'[^']*'\s*:\s*)` replace with empty string.
https://regex101.com/r/827EYK/1

Regex 2:  `(?m)\s*'\s*(.*?)\s*'\s*(?:,\s*|$)` replace with `r"\1\\n"`
https://regex101.com/r/TyuDMt/1

Regex 3:  `(.*?)\\n(.*?)\\n` replace with `r'"\1":"\2", \r\n'`
https://regex101.com/r/zoroi7/1

---

To fix that thing with the uneven numbers (ie. half a pair), you can
at least cauterize it, and identify it on the line level.
Requires a different *Regex 2* and an intermediate one to add the
extra *half pair* so at least it doesn't spill over and contaminate the next line.

It just depends on how far you want to go with this.
Obviously, pair validation can be accomplished right at the beginning
with a single regex. There are multiple options on what you can do about it.